# Error 10061 - server listening but client not connecting

Tags: c++, sockets, visual-c++, tcp, winsock2

Windows 10, Microsoft Visual Studio 2019, C++

I am learning TCP communication on my own, and I am using the [WinSock2 information page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/) to build a simple program where I can send data from myself to myself.

I created the server side of the program in my `main.cpp` file, but I am unsure where to place the code of the client side.

My code is a duplicate of the provided example code on Microsoft's website, as I want to get the example to run before writing my own program which will use threads. [Server Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/complete-server-code), [Client Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/complete-client-code).

I have placed the server and client codes in separate programs, which I am running together. Both programs are on my laptop. First, I click run on the server, then a few seconds later I click run on the client. The issue is the client is not able to connect to the server (receiving error code 10061). I have tried many different port numbers, but none have worked (around ten different numbers, ranging from 1024 to 50000).

The strange thing is, when I open a command prompt window and type: `netstat -abno | findstr <port_number>`, it tells me there is a TCP address listening. It does not show anything before or after running the program, so I am certain it is due to the server program requesting it to listen.

Here is a picture of the command prompt when I set the `<port_number>` to 15280:

[image]

Is there a solution to this? I have checked many questions on SO and other websites, but none have given me the solution to this problem. They have only told me what the problem is, which I already know.

The only change in the code is the definition of DEFAULT_PORT which I changed a few times to test different port numbers. I also changed the first parameter of the getaddrinfo to NULL, since I have no argc or argv values. I had some printf statements to figure out where the program was stopping but have removed them. Also, I do not have the for loop from the complete code, I put together the code snippets of the program which I walked through from start to finish.

Server Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <Windows.h>

#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

#define DEFAULT_PORT "15280"
#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512

int main()
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult;
    
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }

    addrinfo *result = nullptr;
    addrinfo *ptr = nullptr;
    addrinfo hints;

    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    iResult = getaddrinfo(NULL, DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    SOCKET ListenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    ListenSocket = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);
    if (ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("Error at socket(): %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    iResult = bind(ListenSocket, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("bind failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    if (listen(ListenSocket, SOMAXCONN) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("Listen failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    SOCKET ClientSocket;
    ClientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, nullptr, nullptr);
    if (ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("accept failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    int iSendResult;
    int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;

    do {
        iResult = recv(ClientSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
        if (iResult > 0) {
            printf("Bytes printed: %d\n", iResult);
            iSendResult = send(ClientSocket, recvbuf, iResult, 0);
            if (iSendResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                printf("send failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
                closesocket(ClientSocket);
                WSACleanup();
                return 1;
            }
            printf("Bytes sent: %d\n", iSendResult);
        }
        else if (iResult == 0) {
            printf("Connection closing...\n");
        }
        else {
            printf("recv failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(ClientSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }
    } while (iResult > 0);

    iResult = shutdown(ClientSocket, SD_SEND);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("shutdown failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ClientSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    closesocket(ClientSocket);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

Client Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>

#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "Mswsock.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "AdvApi32.lib")

#define DEFAULT_PORT "15280"
#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult;
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }
    addrinfo* result = nullptr;
    addrinfo* ptr = nullptr;
    addrinfo hints;
    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    // first param is argv[1]
    iResult = getaddrinfo(NULL, DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    ptr = result;
    ConnectSocket = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype, ptr->ai_protocol);
    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("Error at socket(): %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    iResult = connect(ConnectSocket, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("Error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    }
    freeaddrinfo(result);
    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("Unable to connect to server!\n");
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;
    const char *sendbuf = "this is a test";
    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    
    iResult = send(ConnectSocket, sendbuf, (int)strlen(sendbuf), 0);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("send failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Bytes Sent: %d\n", iResult);
    iResult = shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_SEND);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("shutdown failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    do {
        iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
        if (iResult > 0) {
            printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);
        }
        else if (iResult == 0) {
            printf("Connection closed\n");
        }
        else {
            printf("recv failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        }
    } while (iResult > 0);

    iResult = shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_SEND);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("shutdown failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The server must `bind`, then `listen` and finally `accept`, with the `accept` often in a loop so you can keep on accepting more connections. It would be helpful if you showed your best attempt so that we may understand what you have tried and better compose worthwhile answers.

Comment: "*I am not sure where to put [the `accept()` and `bind()` and `listen()` functions]*" - wherever you want that suits your needs. "*Would I place each in a separate program and somehow run them simultaneously?*" - you could, yes. But that is not a requirement. For instance, you could use `connect()` and `bind()`/`listen()`/`accept()` in separate threads within a single program instead. "*If so, how is this done and how will I ensure they work together?*" - simply create 2 separate projects, compile them, and run them. What is hard about that?

Comment: "*The help page does not show where the client side of the code should be placed (such as another file or another separate program).*" - yes, it does.  The example Server and Client are implemented as separate programs. As evident by each having its own `main()` function, and the fact that each is documented as a "complete application", hence 2 separate programs.

Comment: I updated my question just now to help with the clarity. My trouble now is I am not sure how to run the two programs at once. I can have one program open but another debugger will not open until the first program has completed its run.

Comment: You can *run* multiple programs simultaneously, but you can't *debug* two programs simultaneously in 1 IDE, as the debugger can only be attached to 1 process at a time. So either have 2 debuggers running, otherwise use external logging to debug the programs in parallel.

Comment: Ah, I see so simply run with Ctrl + f5 on each program thank you, I have always run my programs with the debugger. One more question: when I run without debugging, it seems the name of the program that opens is still called a debugger. Is that supposed to be the case? Also, when I open two VS programs it seems I am allowed to debug both at once, not sure if I am doing this right

Comment: @RemyLebeau I took your advice and placed each of the programs separately, I now encounter a new problem which  I detailed in the second half of the post. According to command prompt, the port I am using is listening but the client is not able to connect

Comment: Error 10061 is `WSAECONNREFUSED` ("No connection could be made because the target computer actively refused it"), which usually means either 1) there is no server listening on the IP/Port being connected to; 2) a server is listening on the IP/port, but its backlog of pending connections is full; or 3) the connection is being blocked by a firewall/anti-(virus|malware) tool. Please show your actual code for both server and client. It is not enough to just claim to copy Microsoft's examples, you might have broken something when copying it, so we need to see the real code you are actually running.

Comment: I added the code to the post but the few changes I listed are minor. I did receive a firewall notification (do not recall which program triggered it, I think it was the server) and I clicked allow. I have not received a firewall notification since then

Comment: Hmm, I created two fresh programs - copy pasted server and client separately, made the client simply int main(), set client's getaddrinfo first param to NULL, and it works as intended now. I must have changed something(s) without noticing. Thank you! one last followup, is there a way to print what is being sent and received in each run terminal ?What I mean is: client sends and prints: Sending " <string printed>" and server receives and prints: Message recieved: " <string printed>". As of now, I only see the number of bytes sent and received (14) in the example, which is the num of chars sent

Comment: Of course it is possible. When sending, simply print what is being sent, eg: `printf("Sending: %s\n", sendbuf); iResult = send(ConnectSocket, sendbuf, strlen(sendbuf), 0);` and likewise when reading: `iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0); if (iResult > 0) { printf("Message received: %.*s\n", iResult, recvbuf); }`